# Java WebSocket Client Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

I want to create a spring boot app with a web socket client that connects to a web socket server.

As an example, I used the Getting Started guide you can find in Spring Boot.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

In this example, you create a web socket server using spring boot and you connect to it using JavaScript.

I want to run that server and connect to it using another spring boot application that creates a WebSocketClient object.

This is the WebSocketClientConfiguration class that I created in the Spring Boot client App

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebSocketClient webSocketClient() {
        final WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();

        final WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        final StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
        stompClient.connect("ws://localhost:8080", sessionHandler);
        return client;
    }
}
```

But in my class MyStompSessionHandler, in handleTransportError method I can see that the exception is

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server [200] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you have this sample WebSocket Client project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured out. The reason it was failing it is because you need to put this in the URL

```
ws://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket
```

Like this `URI.create("ws://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket")`

Comment: Uri is accepted with different signature of .connect() that also accepts WebSocketHttpHeaders in 2nd argument. Could you share the code snippet working for you ?